# Gmail API users.messages.list does not return all messages

Tags: java, java-7, gmail-api

I'm struggling with the GMail API in Java 7. I call the `users.messages.list` endpoint to retrieve all the sent mails of a user in the past 6 months. And the calls only returns very few of them (in the past few days only).

Are you aware in limitations in GMail API (The period cannot be that long ? Or is it too far in the past ?)

This is my code if it helps

```
Gmail.Users.Messages.List request_sent = service.users().messages().list(USER_EMAIL);
request_sent.setFields("messages(id),nextPageToken,resultSizeEstimate")
                    .setMaxResults((long) 50)
                    .setIncludeSpamTrash(true)
                    .setQ("in:sent after:"+current_date_minus_6_months+" before:"+current_date);
log.info("Q = \"" + "in:sent after:"+current_date_minus_6_months+" before:"+current_date+"\"");
/* This displays Q = "in:sent after:2017/02/17 before:2017/08/17" */

ListMessagesResponse sent_messages;
do {
  sent_messages = request_sent.execute();
  log.info("NB MESSAGES = " + sent_messages.getMessages().size());
  request_sent.setPageToken(sent_messages.getNextPageToken());

} while (sent_messages.getNextPageToken() != null && sent_messages.getNextPageToken().length() > 0);
```

Comment: your code says maximum result as 50 (setMaxResults((long) 50))

Comment: it didn't work without this part either, and I iterate over pages so I guess the problem cannot come from here, right ? (I got only 6 emails, when I should get tens...)

Comment: What is your format of `current_date_minus_6_months`? Try it in seconds since the epoch (i.e. `after:1487337090`)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I tried with timestamps in s and ms. Didn't change. I even tried without `q` and it only returned mails from August so the problem might not be with the API.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, did you get its solution